# How to detect if skype is installed using javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, mime-types, skype

I've seen many answers to this issue like this:

```
if (typeof(navigator.mimeTypes["application/x-skype"]) == "object") {
     return true;
} 
else return false;
```

But it doesn't seem to work, I have skype installed in my PC and in my android, and both return false.

I tried to find, and skype doesn't have any mimetype register. Is there another way to verify?

Thanks :)

Comment: `if (new ActiveXObject("Skype.Detection")) return true;`

Comment: @Cory I've tried that, it returns false the same.

Comment: @R.T. ActiveX is microsoft only :/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add one more check it like this:

```
if (new ActiveXObject("Skype.Detection")) 
   return true;
```

Comment: Wouldn't this only work in IE?

Comment: @RocketHazmat:- Yes for Firefox and other versions OP has already added the code.

Comment: @RocketHazmat:- Updated my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: @MarcioOliveira:- I am aware that ActiveX is for IE only. So for which browser you are looking for. You code should work for firefox and IE both :)

Comment: @MarcioOliveira:- Did you try this:- `if (navigator.mimeTypes["application/x-skype"]) return true`

Comment: @R.T. I want to verify to mobile devices mainly. So android navigator & chrome, safari, and IE. The others would be good as well.

Comment: @R.T. Yes I tried that, it returns false as well